# A lower bound on the $L^2$ norm of a Dirichlet polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, lower-bounds

**The Question.** Suppose $0 < \alpha < \beta$ are fixed, and $a_n$ is an arbitrary sequence of real numbers.  Is it known how to bound from below
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{T} \Big| \sum_{\alpha T < n < \beta T} a_n n^{-it} \Big|^2 dt?
\end{equation*}

**What I know.** The mean value theorem for Dirichlet polynomials will tell us
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{T} \Big| \sum_{n \leq N} a_n n^{-it} \Big|^2 dt = (T + O(N)) \sum_{n \leq N} |a_n|^2,
\end{equation*}
and the implied constant is absolute.  This takes care of $\beta$ small enough.

If $\beta$ is large, and $\alpha$ is small, then one can use the method of Rudnick and Soundararajan (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601498), as follows.  By Cauchy-Schwarz, 
\begin{equation*}
\Big|\int_0^{T} \Big(\sum_{n \leq N} a_n n^{-it} \Big) \Big(\sum_{m \leq M} a_m m^{it} \Big) dt \Big|^2 \leq \int_0^{T} \Big| \sum_{n \leq N} a_n n^{-it} \Big|^2 dt \int_0^{T} \Big| \sum_{n \leq M} a_n n^{-it} \Big|^2 dt.
\end{equation*}
Choosing $M$ small enough, say $M \leq \varepsilon T$, allows the computation of the left hand side above (the diagonal terms dominate).  The mean value theorem for Dirichlet polynomials treats the sum over $m \leq M$ on the right hand side.  Rearranging, one gets a lower bound
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{T} \Big| \sum_{n \leq N} a_n n^{-it} \Big|^2 dt \gg T \sum_{n \leq \varepsilon T} |a_n|^2.
\end{equation*}
However, if $a_n = 0$ for $n \leq \varepsilon T$, then this method breaks down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be no such bound if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are suitably large.  For example, using the first derivative test (see e.g. Titchmarsh Chapter 4) 
one can see that if $T\le t\le 2T$ then 
$$
\sum_{10T\le n \le 20T} n^{it} = O(1). 
$$ 
Therefore 
$$ 
\int_T^{2T} \Big| \sum_{10T \le n\le 20 T} n^{it} \Big|^2 dt \ll T
$$ 
whereas one might have initially expected a diagonal contribution of size $T^2$.

(If you're really interested in the interval $[0,T]$ rather than the dyadic $[T,2T]$ then twist the above example by $\chi_{-4}$ say. )

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I  still wonder what kind of lower bound is true, even if it is smaller than what one might expect looking only at the diagonal terms.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you're looking for.  For example, consider a smoothed version (smooth the sum over $n$) of the example (and use Poisson summation).  Seems to me that can be very small for all $T\le t\le 2T$.

Comment: I think your example indicates that to get a reasonable lower bound one needs to require cancellation in $\sum_n a_n a_{n+h} $ for nonzero $h$.  This clarifies the situation.

Comment: I search on Google that (the paper http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa84/aa8426.pdf by Goldston and Gonek) in the truncated interval $[\alpha T,\beta T]$ the asymptotic (Theorem 1) was obtained under the restrictions (6),(7),(8). This shows that the low bound is closely related to the propeties of the real sequences $a_n.$ I also feel that when $M\le\epsilon T $, "the diagonal terms dominate" may be inaccuate.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @H.Flip, it confirms my remark that it is necessary to control the corellations $\sum_n a_n a_{n+h}$ to get a lower bound.  Why do you say you don't think the diagonal terms dominate when $M \leq \varepsilon T$?  With a smoothing factor in $T$, both $m$ and $n$ must be close to each other.

Comment: Forgive my limited capaicty if the mistakes are making. I think $dominate$ maybe depends on the choices of $a_m$. Note the integral with respect to $t$ is $\le |\log^{-1}(n/m)|$. For off-diagonal terms, $m,n$ can be restricted to $n>m,|m-n|=\Delta$ with $\Delta\le m\le M$. The off-diagonal terms can be bounded by $\ll \sum_{m\le M}m |a_m| \sum_{\Delta\le m}|a_{m+\Delta}|/\Delta$ which is big if $a_m>0$ for any $m$, and one of $a_m$ for $M<m\le 2M$ is sufficiently large, $T/\epsilon^2$, say.